# How to prevent octadecimal conversion of a number in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is coming in from another system so I can't simply load the array with values as strings. In the array are IDs that are all numeric. However, some of the IDs have a leading zero and the leader zero must be there as part of the ID.  PHP is converting these IDs to octadecimal.  How to I prevent this so I have access to the actual ID that is in the array?

For example:

```
$ids=array(01234,1234);
$ids= array_map(function($var){ return (string) $var; }, $ids);
foreach ($ids as $id){
    echo $id;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Produces:
668
1234

As you can see I've tried to convert each element in the array to a string prior to doing anything with it, but it's still coming in as octadecimal.

Comment: leading zero is lost in first line, before any other conversions, use quotes around numbers to preserve, like `array('01234','1234')`

Comment: How is the request to this "another system" made, via http? This is strange, because everything i've seen coming, from outside to php, comes as strings, not integers.

Comment: As I stated, I can't add quotes around the data coming in.  I have no control over that.

Comment: I listed the issue incorrectly in that the data is coming from another sorce like this:

    {
    ids:[01234,654987]
    }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is to modify the string before I do anything with it, adding quotes around all the elements in the string prior to using json_decode.

```
 $ids=str_replace(["[",",","]"],['["','","','"]'],$ids);
```

Comment: This does not work as you already have the $ids variable set, https://3v4l.org/M9eMq

Answer (score 0):

As @IlyaBursov said, you loose the `0` in the first line. You need to get the string version of wherever the system is getting those values. You cannot keep the leading zero if you use an integer data type.

Pass it as a string and it will maintain that leading `0`.

Here is a functional example of the method described above, [Run it here](https://3v4l.org/d2AhE)

```
$ids=array('01234','1234');
$ids= array_map(function($var){ return (string) $var; }, $ids);
foreach ($ids as $id){
    echo $id;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Produces,

```
01234<br />1234<br />
```

Comment: `$ids = array_map('strval', $ids);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, that would work as well - but in any case, he still needs to get the string version of wherever the system is getting those values.

Comment: I have tried  
    $ids = array_map('strval', $ids);

It does not work.